# Error installing cpp-ethereum in homebrew

Tags: cpp-ethereum

I am getting this error when attempting to install cpp-ethereum in homebrew. Not sure where to begin...please help!

```
/Users/Macbook/projects/ethereum
==> brew install cpp-ethereum
==> Installing cpp-ethereum from ethereum/ethereum
==> Cloning https://github.com/ethereum/webthree-umbrella.git
Updating /Library/Caches/Homebrew/cpp-ethereum--git
==> Checking out branch develop
Synchronizing submodule url for 'evmjit'
Synchronizing submodule url for 'deps'
==> cmake -DCMAKE_C_FLAGS_RELEASE=-DNDEBUG -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE=-DNDEBUG -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local/Cellar/cpp-ethereum/1.2.5 -DCMAKE_BU
==> make
Last 15 lines from /Users/Macbook/Library/Logs/Homebrew/cpp-ethereum/02.make:
cd /tmp/cpp-ethereum-20160529-9027-27dkja/libethereum/evmjit/libevmjit && /usr/local/Library/ENV/4.3/clang++   -DETH_EVMJIT -DETH_FATDB -DETH_FRONTIER -DETH_TRUE -DSHAREDLIB -D__STDC_CONSTANT_MACROS -D__STDC_LIMIT_MACROS -Devmjit_EXPORTS -I/tmp/cpp-ethereum-20160529-9027-27dkja/libethereum -I/tmp/cpp-ethereum-20160529-9027-27dkja/libethereum/include -I/tmp/cpp-ethereum-20160529-9027-27dkja -I/tmp/cpp-ethereum-20160529-9027-27dkja/include -I/tmp/cpp-ethereum-20160529-9027-27dkja/gen -I/usr/local/include -I/tmp/cpp-ethereum-20160529-9027-27dkja/libethereum/gen -I/tmp/cpp-ethereum-20160529-9027-27dkja/libethereum/evmjit/include -I/usr/local/opt/llvm37/lib/llvm-3.7/include -I/tmp/cpp-ethereum-20160529-9027-27dkja/libethereum/evmjit/libevmjit/gen  -std=c++11 -Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -Wno-sign-conversion -Wno-unknown-pragmas -std=c++11 -fpermissive -fno-rtti -fvisibility=hidden -O3 -DNDEBUG -DETH_RELEASE -fPIC   -Wall -Wextra -Werror -Wno-unknown-pragmas -fPIC -fstack-protector-strong -fstack-protector -Wno-unused-function -Wno-dangling-else -o CMakeFiles/evmjit.dir/Cache.cpp.o -c /tmp/cpp-ethereum-20160529-9027-27dkja/libethereum/evmjit/libevmjit/Cache.cpp
clang: : : : erroerrorerror: error: : error: ununknown argument: '-fstack-protector-strong': known argument: '-fstack-protector-strong'
unknown unknown argument: '-fstack-protector-strong'
: unknown argument: '-fstack-protector-strong'
make[2]: *** [libethereum/evmjit/libevmjit/CMakeFiles/evmjit.dir/BasicBlock.cpp.o] Error 1
make[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
make[2]: *** [libethereum/evmjit/libevmjit/CMakeFiles/evmjit.dir/Cache.cpp.o] Error 1
make[2]: *** [libethereum/evmjit/libevmjit/CMakeFiles/evmjit.dir/Array.cpp.o] Error 1
make[2]: *** [libethereum/evmjit/libevmjit/CMakeFiles/evmjit.dir/JIT-c.cpp.o] Error 1
make[2]: *** [libethereum/evmjit/libevmjit/CMakeFiles/evmjit.dir/Arith256.cpp.o] Error 1
make[2]: *** [libethereum/evmjit/libevmjit/CMakeFiles/evmjit.dir/JIT.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [libethereum/evmjit/libevmjit/CMakeFiles/evmjit.dir/all] Error 2
[  2%] Built target ethereum_BuildInfo.h
[  2%] Built target cpp-ethereum_BuildInfo.h
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Comment: what is your os x version ? El Capitan ?

Answer (score 1):

Please ensure that you do:

- brew update
- brew upgrade

Before anything else.  You should be getting prebuilt bottles.  The fact that it is building from source indicates that something is wrong before you even start.

Only OS X Yosemite and OS X El Capitan are supported?   Maybe you have an older version?   Maybe you haven't got the latest xcode installed?

Guides are here:

- http://www.ethdocs.org/en/latest/ethereum-clients/cpp-ethereum/building-from-source/osx.html
- http://www.ethdocs.org/en/latest/ethereum-clients/cpp-ethereum/installing-binaries/osx-homebrew.html

Still having problems, come over to https://gitter.im/ethereum/cpp-ethereum and we'll help you out.